# How to append two different elements to a list

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I am using `beautifulsoup` to extract href links from a url page and then append the url name and the extracted links to create list in a list. For example, for each url, I want to access the page and extract urls within the link, and then append to a list in a list to create:

```
[['www.example.com', 'www.example.com/extractedlink1', 'www.example.com/extractedlink2'],['www.apple.com', 'www.apple.com/exractedlink1']...]
```

The part I am having trouble is appending the two elements in a list in a list. Below, `url_list` is a list with the urls to be accessed for extraction ex)`['www.example.com', 'www.apple.com'....]`

```
url_and_extracted = []

for i in range(0,len(url_list)):
    url = url_list[i]
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    html = driver.page_source
    driver.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for div in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class" : "article-content entry-content"}):
        url_and_extracted.append([url_list[i],str(div.find("a")['href'])])
```

But I don't think the last part is right, this would lead to multiple lists with the same original url when there are more than one links extracted from one url. What I want is one list within list with original url and the extracted hrefs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a simple approach of collecting the links, then adding the url before you add it to your master list:

```
url_and_extracted = []
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

for url in url_list:
   links = [] # collect the links here
   driver.get(url)
   time.sleep(2)
   html = driver.page_source
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
   for div in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class" : "article-content entry-content"}):
       links.append(div.find("a")['href'])

   url_and_extracted.append([url]+links) # add the url with [url] + links
                                         # to the main list.
```

Answer (score 0):

use `dict` to map the relation of urls:

```
{'www.example.com': ['www.example.com/extractedlink1', 'www.example.com/extractedlink2']}
```

the reason why you code is not working is this part:

```
for div in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class" : "article-content entry-content"}):
        url_and_extracted.append([url_list[i],str(div.find("a")['href'])])
```

you should append to `url_and_extracted` in each iterration of `i`, not the `div`.

code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
url_and_extracted = []
# for i in range(0,len(url_list)):
for i in in url_list:
    d = defaultdict(list)
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    html = driver.page_source
    driver.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for div in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class" : "article-content entry-content"}):
        d[i].append(div.find("a")['href'])
    url_and_extracted.append(d)
```

Comment: In this case, you don't need the original `url_and_extracted` at all.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I ran the code, it worked but the result is quite strange, it is dictionary form but there is "defaultdict(<type 'list'>" inserted in between each dictionary item.

Comment: So? Don't look at how something is printed - that's just a data representation.

Comment: @宏杰李  I found a problem, when I print d, I only get the result for one link,  not multiple. For instance, I only get result for www.example.com and not for apple.com. Why isn't append working?

Comment: @宏杰李 Ok, I fixed the problem myself, you have to define d outside the loop.